# Applying the weight to the mesh, but it shrinks when I rotate up

Tags: mesh, bones, weight-painting

It looks perfect right now. [image] But when I rotate it, it shrinks. Am I applying to much weight to the previous bone when I link them up for the hair to shrink?  the bones are not fallowing the mesh when I applied the weight. Only slightly. Why? [image]

Comment: How is the child bone weight like? And if you have multiple modifiers, please upload a screenshot of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the hair vertices (which i suppose correctly weighted to the two rotated hair bones) are weighted also to some body bones.
To remove thoose unwanted weights enter edit mode, select all hair vertices, select all the body vertex groups (one by one) and click "remove" after every selection.

If this doesn't solver the problem, please upload your file.

[image]